# How to: Converting array of bytes to InputStream

Tags: java, io, arrays, inputstream, apache-commons

With Apache Commons it is very simple to convert `InputStream` to `byte[]`,

`static byte[] toByteArray(InputStream input)`

but I can't find the opposite method. What's the most popular/straightforward way of converting array of bytes to InputStream object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [ByteArrayInputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html)

Comment: Thanks! I started looking in Apache Commons and that was a mistake :-)